# Concatenate attributes from multiple HTML elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a string representing the name of each element of a container, each name being separated by a comma. I came up with the following jQuery function:

```
var list = "";

container.children("*").each(function()
    {
        if(list)
        {
            list += ",";
        }
        list += jQuery(this).data("item-name");
    });
```

I am wondering whether there would be a more effective/clean way of gathering an attribute without using the `each()` function in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array and then join the items with commas:

```
var list = $('.element').children().map(function () {
  return $(this).data("item-name");
}).get().join(',');
```

Basic example:

```js
var list = $('.element').children().map(function () {
  return $(this).data("item-name");
}).get().join(',');

document.body.textContent = list;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
  <div data-item-name="name1"></div>
  <div data-item-name="name2"></div>
  <div data-item-name="name3"></div>
  <div data-item-name="name4"></div>
</div>
```